# Symmetric, antisymmetric and mixed symmetry particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, identical-particles

Can someone explain to me the concept of symmetric, antisymmetric, and mixed symmetry when talking about the states of identical particles?

Comment: You might find this useful http://joshphysics.com/articles/ParticlesAndPermutations.html

Comment: @joshphysics link is dead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may indeed have heard that an electron is antisymmetric, whereas a photon is symmetric. What does this mean?

Suppose I have a system of several electrons. They could be orbiting a nucleus, for example. Their behaviour is described by a *wave-function*, $\psi$. If I swap the positions of two electrons labled $a$ and $b$ in the system, the wave-function will pick up a minus sign,
$$
\psi_{ab} = - \psi_{ba}.
$$
Thus we say that electrons are antisymmetric. By the [spin-statistics theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem), all fermions (electrons, leptons, quarks etc) are antisymmetric.

If, on the other hand, the behaviour was simply,
$$
\psi_{ab} = \psi_{ba},
$$
the particle is said to be symmetric. By the [spin-statistics theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem), all bosons (photons, $W$, $Z$ etc) are symmetric.

What is the physical meaning of this? What are the implications? Well, one famous implication is the [Pauli exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle). Suppose I have two indistinguishable electrons (with the same *quantum numbers*), they cannot be labelled independently, we simply have $a=b$. What is their wave-function? It must be antisymmetric, so we have
$$
\psi_{ab} = - \psi_{ba} \Rightarrow \psi_{aa} = - \psi_{aa} = 0
$$
i.e. it is impossible to have antisymmetric particles in identical quantum states.

Comment: any idea about the mixed symmetry though ?